# How to create default branch with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git

When I am creating a repository in Git it says "This repository's default branch is empty!"

Earlier I had a master branch and a source button with SSH, HTTP.

So how can I create this default branch, without using the terminal?

Comment: brunch with git? Doesn't sound so romantic...

Comment: Brunch is better without Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx all but i resolved my issue.

In repository Admin panel just need to check GitHub Pages, it creates "gh-pages" branch and shows a source button with SSH, HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new, empty, git repository you will have an empty default branch until your first commit.

When using EGit, you can create a new git repository from the Git Repositories view.  See [Creating a Repository](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_Repository).  When that's done, I create my workspace projects, uncheck "default location", and specify a directory within my newly created Git repo.  There's more of a discussion on creating git repos in relation to a workspace in [Considerations for Git Repos](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse).